# AppWidget multiple instances stops refreshing

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I have **6** bitmaps in my AppWidget and set image view bitmap on each refresh as :

```
rviews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.time1, theBitmapLayer1);
rviews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.time2, theBitmapLayer2);
rviews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.time3, theBitmapLayer3);
rviews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.time4, theBitmapLayer4);
rviews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.time5, theBitmapLayer5);
rviews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.time6, theBitmapLayer6);
```

Then I update my AppWidget(s) using this :

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new int[] { widgetId }, rviews);
```

It's working properly if I insert just a single instance of Widget on desktop.
But on some devices (e.g. Nexus 4, Os 4.3) if I insert **5~6** copies of widget on desktop it stops refreshing. After this not only on widget crashes but also all other app-widgets. The only solution is to reboot device.

This problem exists on Nexus 7, but not on old Samsung Galaxy Ace ( Os 2.3.6)